# Método com retorno pede retorno que já foi dado

Tags: java, método, return

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
public class Exemplar {
    private boolean disponivel;
    private int codigo;
    // seus setters e getters
}
```

e esta outra:

```
public class Biblioteca {
    private ArrayList<Exemplar> exemplares;

    public boolean emprestar(int codigo){
       for(Exemplar e : exemplares){
           if (e.getCodigo() == codigo){
               return e.isDisponivel();
           }else{
               return false;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Este método `emprestar()` está dando o erro de

> "missing return statement"

sendo que já defini os `return` dentro do `for`, o que há de errado?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

O que está errado é faltar um `return`.

Um método que exija um retorno tem que ter em todos os caminhos possíveis de execução o correspondente `return`

Caso **exemplares** não tenha itens o for(foreach) não é executado, e não é encontrado nenhum return.

Adicione um return no final do bloco foreach:

```
public class Biblioteca {
    private ArrayList<Exemplar> exemplares;
    public boolean emprestar(int codigo) {
       for (Exemplar e : exemplares) {
           if (e.getCodigo() == codigo) return e.isDisponivel();
           else return false;
       }
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas desse jeito ele só vai fazer uma interação por causa do `return false` e a decisão não for satisfeita?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Eu apenas respondi à pergunta. Qualquer outra coisa que acrescentasse seria "chute".

Comment: O seu código faz uma vez o for esse é meu questionamento!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Eu entendo a sua questão, foi a primeira coisa em que reparei quando analisei o código. No entanto, pode ser isso que AP queira que o código faça, não sei.

Comment: Foi um alerta somente. Eu entendo só quis mesmo ajudar

Answer (score 1):

E se nem entrar no `for`? Este mecanismo só será executado se tiver algum elemento na coleção, se a coleção de dados estiver vazia nem entra no laço, aí vai para o fim do método e o que ele está retornando? Nada! Falta um `return` neste caso e que faça sentido, então "parece" que `false` é adequado, mas não tenho certeza sem saber os requisitos.

O `for` não deixa de ser uma execução condicional (*branch*), então ela precisa ser considerada. Você tem que considerar todos caminhos possíveis na hora de dar um `return` no método. Algo assim poderia resolver:

```
public class Biblioteca {
    private ArrayList<Exemplar> exemplares;
    public boolean emprestar(int codigo) {
       for (Exemplar e : exemplares) {
           if (e.getCodigo() == codigo) return e.isDisponivel();
           else return false;
       }
       return false;
    }
}
```

Eu acho que todo o código tem outros problemas, mas só posso resolver este aqui. Um exemplo é que isto só avaliará o primeiro item da coleção de dados, aconteça o que acontecer ele encerrá o método após o primeiro item, então acho que colocou o `return` aleatoriamente de forma equivocada, não pode colocar um `return` em qualquer lugar, talvez queira fazer isto:

```
public class Biblioteca {
    private ArrayList<Exemplar> exemplares;
    public boolean emprestar(int codigo) {
       for (Exemplar e : exemplares) if (e.getCodigo() == codigo) return e.isDisponivel();
       return false;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/ReturnAllPath.java).

Desta forma se achar um código que bate com o que está buscando ele retorna se está disponível ou não conforme o método `isDisponivel()`, mas se nem achar o código, ou seja, percorrer tudo e nenhum código for igual, então certamente deve retornar um falso porque se nem o código tem, certamente está indisponível.

O nome do método parece errado, ele está fazendo uma verificação não está emprestando nada.

Comment: Mas desse jeito ele só vai fazer uma interação por causa do `return false` e a decisão não for satisfeita? (o seu primeiro código)

Comment: Por isso eu fiz o segundo. Eu não posso aformar o que ele quer, não tem requisito. O meu segundo código faz igual ao seu mas de forma muito mais simples.

Comment: Simples !!! Ou um código que muitas vezes é difícil leitura. O seu código são de difícil leitura pessoas que não sabem programar fica complicado entender o meu é mais didático e não tem problema algum fazer assim. O seu está correto mas de difícil compreensão pra quem não sabe programar

Comment: Eu não faço código para pessoas que não sabem programar, eu ajudo pessoas aprenderem programar. Manter o status quo não é meu objetivo, eu quero ver as pessoas crescerem. Criado estado desnecessário, desvio extra é complexidade, é código complicado e todo mundo que aprendeu programar de verdade sabe disso, algumas pessoas ficaram paradas no que aprenderam a primeira vez e só enxerga assim. Eu sempre vou mostrar o jeito melhor de fazer. As pessoas escolhem o que querem seguir.

Answer (score 0):

O `return` pelo erro apresentando precisa existir no final do método, então, mude seu código assim:

```
public class Biblioteca {
    private ArrayList<Exemplar> exemplares;

    public boolean emprestar(int codigo) {
       boolean status = false;
       for(Exemplar e : exemplares){
           if (e.getCodigo() == codigo) {
               status = e.isDisponivel();
               break;
           }
       }
       return status;
    }
}
```

Vale lembrar que isso é referente a satisfazer ou não uma condição e geralmente (não é obrigatório, mas, nesse caso é) o `return` deve ser o último código em algum método de retorno. Existe `return` que é colocado no meio de um fluxo, mas, para isso no final do método precisa ter algum retorno, se não satisfazer algum comparação ou estrutura.

Nesse caso o `for` depois da comparação do `if` se for satisfeita repasso o valor para a variável `status` e logo após para o fluxo com `break`, para que a partir dá li sai dessa estrutura de repetição e logo após retorne o valor.

Eu acredito que você precisa percorrer até satisfazer a comparação do `if` se não vai retornar `false`. Tem um coisa errada nesse código e se o `e.getCodigo()` existir e o `e.isDisponivel()` for `false` você nunca vai saber realmente se o código não foi encontrado ou se ele foi encontrado e o seu `isDisponivel()` também é `false`.

Não seria melhor retornar um valor `char`, uma estrutura complexa, um `integer` sei lá, tipo **0** para não encontrado, **1** para encontrado mas, `status = false` e **2** para encontrado para `status = true`, seria uma ideia que define realmente o que esse método realmente precisa retornar ou até retorna do item que foi encontrado (`exemplar`) se não for `null`, claro que isso depende do seu contexto que não está bem descrito na pergunta.